# Sitecore SXA Video Gallery component is not supporting iOS devices

Tags: sxa

I have used the Sitecore SXA Video Gallery component but in mobile view it is not supporting(not able to see the videos) to iPhones,iPads. I am facing the below error

Please help me how can I resolve this issue.

[image]